# How to setup UART on STM32 Nucleo board for a peripheral UART device?

Tags: stm32l152

What I've been trying to do is send UART communications from an STM32 L152RE Nucleo board to an ESP32, however when I attempt to send these communications I get nothing on the ESP serial monitor. What I am able to see is the STM32 sending messages to its own serial monitor which is great but not what I want.

What I've read so far is that UART 2 is connected to ST-Link so that it can do specifically what I've been witnessing and it explains how this can be reconfigured to allow for the messages to be sent to a peripheral UART device but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

So in the picture below it says to do this I need to "turn off" SB13 and SB14 and "turn on" SB62 and SB63. I don't really understand how to interpret that, other than to mean "remove resistors from SB13 and SB14 and Place them on SB62 and SB63", is this correct?
[image: STM32 L152RE UART]

I know there are another set of UART pins on the board, can I use those instead somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Your guess ist correct. "SB" means "[Solder Bridge](https://resources.altium.com/p/solder-bridge-jumper-best-practices-pcb-design)". It is just a pair of pads which can be connected with a solder ball, like a simple jumper. Setting SB13 to ON means to connect the pads with a solder ball, setting SB62 to OFF means to remove an existing solder ball connection.

Using a different USART is even easier. Have a look at the [STM32L151xE Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l151qe.pdf) to find out that e.g. USART1 is available on pins PA9 (TX) and PA10 (RX). According to [user manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) of the [NUCLEO-L152RE](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l152re.html#documentation) board these pins are available on the ST morpho connector CN10: PA9 at Pin 21 and PA10 at Pin 33.